# Beamer : display the lines of an array pause by pause ( is there an alternative to \hline ?)

Tags: beamer, overlays, arrays

I would like to display the different lines of an array, using overlays.
However I have trouble with the `\hline` command which seems to include an carriage return. 
Here is a minimal example, I guess what I want is quite obvious:  the same result without the first | on the new line

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \mbox{first line} & bla&bla \\
\hline\pause 
\visible<2->{\mbox{second line} & bla & bla \\
\hline}\pause
\mbox{third line} & bla &bla
\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `$$`, use `\[...\]` instead (for details see [this question and answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/11232)). You can put `\noalign{\pause}` at the end.  Then `\pause` is applied just when the one row is finished and before the next row is started. Also, it is better to use `\text` instead of `\mbox` as the former is more font friendly.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\mode<presentation>
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline \text{first line} & bla&bla \\
\hline\noalign{\pause}
\text{second line} & bla & bla \\
\hline\noalign{\pause}
\text{third line} & bla &bla
\\ \hline
\end{array}\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect. And yes I realised after that I did use the good old $$.. $$. Greetings

Comment: by the way how people do this litlle preview of pdf ? i was not able to do that for my question... (did not look that much).

Comment: thanks as well for your remark on \text instead of \mbox. I did learn qui some with my question :).

Comment: @user42070 I converted the obtained pdf in to `gif` using `imagemagick` and uploaded it.